# New component not found

Tags: laravel, email, components

I've a problem with custom component for email in Laravel 5.8

I'have create a new file : /resources/vendor/mail/html/training.blade.php

In my view file (folder : /resources/views/emails/training/) i have : 
`@component('mail::training')`
instead of :
`@component('mail::message')`

But i've got this error :
View [training] not found ...

Note : if i edit a file like : /resources/views/emails/header.blade.php
I see the modification in the email.

I miss somethings how create a new component ?

Thanks.

**EDIT :**

I found the solution. You need to duplicate the file in each dir :
/vendor/mail/html AND /vendor/mail/text

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:markdown]?

Comment: Because i use markdown in the Class :
return $this->subject(config('app.name'))->markdown('emails.trainings.my-view');

Answer (score 0):

Every vendor component is registred in the serviceProvider of that package. If you want to make your own blade component follow the documentation.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots

Components and slots provide similar benefits to sections and layouts; however, some may find the mental model of components and slots easier to understand. First, let's imagine a reusable "alert" component we would like to reuse throughout our application:

```
<!-- /resources/views/alert.blade.php -->

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    {{ $slot }}
</div>
```

The {{ $slot }} variable will contain the content we wish to inject into the component. Now, to construct this component, we can use the @component Blade directive:

```
@component('alert')
    <strong>Whoops!</strong> Something went wrong!
@endcomponent
```

Comment: Thanks but i found the solution

Comment: Could you share the solution? For other people that have the same question!

Answer (score 0):

if you put your component in "views" folder and remove the prefix 'mail::' in `@component('mail::training')` it should work successfully.

to make Laravel reads views from "views/vendor/mail/html" you can simply add this line `resource_path('views/vendor/mail/html')` to view.php in config folder.